# Session not passing to the view laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect to a route and pass data and I used with but no go and I also used to just simply set the sessions and then fetch them in the view but no go

Controller code

```
if($socialUser) {

   Session::put('redirect', 'student-dashboard');
   Session::save();

   return redirect('/register/candidate');
}
```

View code

```
<?php if(\Session::get('redirect')) {

        $redirect = session('redirect');
        echo $redirect;
        die();
    } 
?>
```

But it never enters this if check and I need data on this view so any advise on this will be helpful.

Please Note :- Session is available in the controller after being sent and I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: Could you try to add `\Session::save();` after `\Session::put()`.

Comment: yes i did and still it is not getting passed

Comment: Could you post your controller method, and where will load this view?

Comment: Please check and advise

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: In your controller session is work. And redirect to other view, the session key isn't work?

Comment: @SalmanZafar 5.6 as mentioned in the question

Comment: Your view code should use `@if`? If you use blade template

Comment: you can just use `return redirect('/register/candidate')->with('redirect','student-dashboard');` in controller as per @qqmydarling

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code where you then instead set $redirect like you ask the if statement:

```
$redirect = \Session::get('redirect');
```

Also if you are using blade templates, you can write the php as;

```
@php
if (\Session::has('redirect'))
{
    $redirect = \Session::get('redirect');
    echo $redirect;
}
@endphp
```

The `if (Session::has('redirect'))` seems to be the proper way to check for whether or not a session exists, according to the Laravel 5.0 documentation, so I'm also leaving that there as a possible change that may help your code work.

Comment: I'd also love to know which view you actually have the php snippet in? Is it in the view for the function in the controller where the "if ($socialuser)" or is it in the actual view that you redirect to, because if it is not in the view you redirect to, it will not echo there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure u need to use `Session::save();` for me its working without it. Try this one.

```
//controller
if($socialUser) {
   Session::put('redirect', 'student-dashboard');
   return redirect('/register/candidate');
}

//view
@php
    use Session; // or without it just using \Session
    if( Session::has('redirect') ){
      $redirect = Session::get('redirect');
      echo $redirect;
      die();
    }
@endphp
```

You can also try to use following syntax in controller

```
 return redirect('/register/candidate')->with('redirect','student-dashboard');
```

And in view

```
@php 
   if(session('redirect')){
     //your code here
   }
@endphp
```

Comment: when using `with()` you cant access it using `session('redirect')`

Comment: @LeenaPatel why not? That's worked for me in an older version of laravel

Comment: when you are using `with()` you need to access it using `$redirect` in blade in Laravel 5.6

Comment: @LeenaPatel I just tested it in Laravel 5.4 and it works successfully

Comment: without using `session` and using `return redirect('/register/candidate')->with('redirect','student-dashboard');`  ? I doubt

Comment: @LeenaPatel yes, without it. You can try if you has doubt. I used that syntax when I redirect user after login to show him a 'success login' message

Answer (score 0):

You can’t redirect in a view. Redirects have a range of HTTP status codes (3XX). If you’ve presented a view, then HTTP headers have already been sent (probably with a 200 OK status).

Instead, perform the redirect in your controller:

```php
if ($socialUser) {
    return redirect('student-dashboard');
}
```

If you need to set the redirect URL in the view for some reason (i.e. you’re passing it to a hidden input) then you’ll need to do just that: pass it as a view parameter. Don’t try setting it in the session. You won’t see any session data set in your controller because the session data is only written *after* a response has been sent (i.e. after your view is rendered).

Comment: I am not redirecting in the view , I just have a variable called $redirect which I am accessing in the view